# TDMA implementation using a variable

Tags: omnet++

I am new to OMNeT++. I have implemented simple TDMA. Now i want to make it dynamic with respect to the number of nodes. As i enter it should automatically assign slots to each node. Right now I have to enter slots in .ini file manually. Example is as shown:

**Manual Procedure:**

```
**.noHost = 10
**.host[0].slotTime = 0.0
**.host[1].slotTime = 0.1
**.host[2].slotTime = 0.2
**.host[3].slotTime = 0.3
**.host[4].slotTime = 0.4
**.host[5].slotTime = 0.5
**.host[6].slotTime = 0.6
**.host[7].slotTime = 0.7
**.host[8].slotTime = 0.8
**.host[9].slotTime = 0.9
```

However, now I want to change it w.r.t. noHost. How can I apply loop in .ini file for this.
Can anyone help? I will be highly obliged.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the special value `index` to achieve this, for example:

```
**.host[*].slotTime = index * 0.1
```

The value of `index` is the index of each submodule in the vector. For example, when evaluating the above expression for `host[6]`, the value of `index` will be `6`. So this will result in the same thing as the manual method you described.

See the corresponding manual section: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:expressions

Comment: where should i define this index? will it be a loop?

Comment: It is built-in. You don't need to define it. It's already defined implicitly.
And since every wildcard assignment will be processed in a "loop" of some sort, yes.

Comment: when i write this expression, it says unsed entry, thats why i am confused.

Comment: I see. That "unused entry" error message has nothing to do with the use of `index`, rather, with the fact that the index is now a wildcard, `*`. And since the IDE does not completely understand wildcard assignments, it thinks that this line is unnecessary, because it does not match any modules. But of course it does, and it should work fine in the actual simulation. So that error message is a false alarm. Not in all cases, but in many, including this one. :) Improving this is on our TODO list, but that list is very long!

Comment: sir problem is resolved. thank you very much. really thanks

Comment: i think i was using this:    **.node[*].slotTime = index*slotTime there was error now i used it directly as **.node[*].slotTime = index*1/noNode. now problem is solved. once more thank you sir

Comment: Interesting. Anyways, if it works, great! If my answer really helped, please consider marking it as accepted, by clicking the green tickmark next to it.